# Flattening a 2D array Haskell

Tags: arrays, list, haskell, flatten

I currently have a 2D array of the form `UArray (Int, Int) Char`, I would like to turn this into a `List` like so:

```
["ffffffffff",
"ffffffffff",
"ffffffffff",
"ffffffffff",
"ffffffffff",
"ffffffffff",
"ffffffffff",
"ffffffffff",
"ffffffffff",
"ffffffffff"]
```

Each `f` is originally a character in the UArray.

Where the `Char`s for each line in the 2D array is turned into a `String`, which, in turn is parsed into a `List` as such `[String]`, however, I have had no luck with the `toList` method from `Data.Foldable`, what functions should I be looking at to achieve this?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I have updated the question I asked prior to this so it is no longer a repeat, the previous question did not go over flattening in a manner which worked for my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generalize this functionality quite a bit, for any tuple of indices, any array type and any element type:

```
import Data.Array.Unboxed 

flatten2D :: (Enum i0, Enum i1, Ix i0, Ix i1, IArray arr x) 
          => arr (i0, i1) x -> [[x]]
flatten2D arr = [ [ arr ! (i0, i1) | i0 <- [min0..max0] ] | i1 <- [min1..max1] ]
  where ((min0, min1), (max0, max1)) = bounds arr
```

The implementation is straightforward: the indices lists are constructed using the `Enum` instance from a minimum and maximum bound. Then you simply get the element at each index. A nested list comprehension accomplishes this in a very nice way.